# Need to implement the view changing functionality by swiping the container view or by taping the corresponding button

Tags: ios, uibutton

In my iOS application i need to implement the functionality like "I have 4 buttons on the Container view, when user tap on the button need to show the respective view on the container view, need to implement the same when user swipe the container view.

Comment: Post your code and the issue you are having with it, now you question looks like a code request which is frowned up.

Answer (score 0):

By the way why are you trying to achieve same goal with two different way ,i.e., button and swipe to present new view. Also it is simple just programmatically create that view(UIView *temp) and give it frame of that container view so as to fit in. Then just [self.containerView addsubview:yourView]. So your goal is achieved. Hope helped you!